# How to use htaccess url rewrite for removing a querystring

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that redirects to a page with a querystring. I need to make that url SEO friendly. The url is

http://www.tasteofkochi.com/dine-detail.php?a=51-fort-kochi-mattanchery

I need it to look like

http://www.tasteofkochi.com/dine-detail/51-fort-kochi-mattanchery

I want to remove the '.php' extension and then replace '?a=' to '/'

Can anybody please let me know how to achieve it.

Comment: `.htaccess` rewrites server side, so for example you put `https://example.com/foo/bar` in your web browsers address bar,  and the webserver sends that to `https://example.com/index.php?foo=bar` .   You can do a 301 redirect from `https://example.com/index.php?foo=bar` to `https://example.com/foo/bar`  -  Something like `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} a=70$` followed by `RewriteRule (.*) /dine-detail/? [R=301,L]` (to perform the redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# 301 redirect any requests for /dine-detail.php?a=xx to /dine-detail/xx
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)a=([^&]+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^dine-detail\.php$ /dine-detail/%1? [R=301,END]

# Rewrite requests for /dine-detail/xx to /dine-detail.php?a=xx
RewriteRule ^dine-detail/(.+)$ dine-detail.php?a=$1 [QSA,END]
```

This does two things. Any requests for the old style URLs get 301 redirected to the new ones (an external 301 redirect, so the URL changes in the browser), and the new ones get silently rewritten to work with the script as if they had never changed (an internal rewrite).

It will only work for the dine-detail.php page. Let me know if you want it to be more generic and work for other pages, but this is what you asked for.

You can use query strings on the new /dine-detail/xxx URLs and the a= will get appended to them. Any query string params on the old URLs, other than a=xxx, will be dropped by the redirect.

It needs to go in a `.htaccess` file in the root of your website or in a `<Directory>` block for the website document root in the main server config.

Comment: I believe this will cause an internal rewrite loop as both rules have the same pattern.

Comment: I know it looks that way, but that's what the `[L]` flag is for, it stands for 'LAST', so no more rules get processed once one of them has matched. [More info here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_).

Comment: No, L doesnt do what you think it does. On htaccess context it works like the continue loop.

Comment: Thanks. In that case it can be replaced with END but L has worked for me before. Think you're right and that was in server config though, just testing now.

Comment: Yes, as you say, L is no good in htaccess. It works with END. Thanks. Have updates the directives.

Comment: END flag is fine. Your rule still causes an infinite loop because you have ended your external redirect. Remove END from your 301 RewriteRule.

Comment: I tried with this, but I am getting a 404 error

The requested URL www.tasteofkochi.com/dine-detail/51-fort-kochi-mattanchery was not found on this server.

Am I missing something here, do I have to have a physical folder with that name? or do I have to put any php code. PLease advise.

Comment: @user2493235
Now I am getting the page but no css has been applied

Comment: @RohitMenon glad it's working. Load your CSS with a forward slash at the beginning to make it an absolute URL. "/dine-detail/" looks like a folder so the browser will try to load it from there if you're using just "style.css", you need "/style.css".

Comment: @starkeen having the [END] flag on the 301 couldn't possibly cause an infinite loop. It's recommended to end processing after causing a redirect, [according to the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r): "You will almost always want to use [R] in conjunction with [L] (that is, use [R,L]) because on its own, the [R] flag prepends http://thishost[:thisport] to the URI, but then passes this on to the next rule in the ruleset, which can often result in 'Invalid URI in request' warnings."